# Insert query with where clause is not working

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am using insert query for add the review of the current user in the database using python and sqlite3. I am sharing the query below . it is not working.

```
c.execute('insert into tableforimagedata(select review from tableforimagedata where id=?) values(?)',(idd,n1))
```

It is showing error as :

```
args = ('near "select": syntax error',) 
  with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of OperationalError object>
```

Comment: You need 2 queries. First to get the id, and then another for insert.

Comment: Can u brief me both queries ?

Comment: Neither the description nor the code are clear enough to understand what you actually want to do. Be more specific; give example data.

Comment: import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import os
import sqlite3

from http import cookies
if 'HTTP_COOKIE' in os.environ:
    cookie_string=os.environ.get('HTTP_COOKIE')
    e1=cookies.SimpleCookie()
    e1.load(cookie_string)
    idd=e1['eidd'].value
    
form=cgi.FieldStorage()
db=sqlite3.connect("cgidb.db")
n1=form.getvalue('revew')
c=db.cursor()
c.execute('insert into tableforimagedata(review) values(?)',(n1,))

Comment: this is my code. and i want the particular text of review should insert according to the id which i am getting through cookies.